# Jquery tooltipster validate file

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, symfony

I want to validate a file before upload it, the field file is required and should be in pdf extension. however when I want to validate it, the script don't show me the errors messages
here is my code

```
<input id="faxtype_file" name="faxtype[file]" class="file  custom-file-upload-hidden" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;" tabindex="-1" type="file"><input class="file-upload-input" type="text"><button type="button" class="file-upload-button" tabindex="-1">upload</button>
```

and in my jquery file:

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("regexphone", function (value, element, regexp) {

           if (regexp.constructor != RegExp)
               regexp = new RegExp(regexp);
           else if (regexp.global)
               regexp.lastIndex = 0;
           return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
       }, "");

       $('#formulaire :input').tooltipster({
           trigger: 'custom', // default is 'hover' which is no good here
           onlyOne: false,    // allow multiple tips to be open at a time
           position: 'right'  // display the tips to the right of the element
       });


       $('#formulaire').validate({ // initialize the plugin
           errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
               $(element).tooltipster('update', $(error).text());
               $(element).tooltipster('show');
           },
           success: function (label, element) {
               $(element).tooltipster('hide');
           },
           rules: {
               'faxtype[faxList]': {
                   required: true,

               },
               'faxtype[file]':{
                   required:true,
                   extension: "docx|rtf|doc|pdf"
               }



           },
           messages: {

               'faxtype[faxList]': {
                   required: "{{ 'message.faxm.listnumber'|trans }}",

               },
               'faxtype[file]':{
                   required:"le fichier est obligatoir",
                   extension: "l'extension doit etre pdf"
               }

           },

       });
```

not that the script validate the faxlist field but not the filed field.

in my twig :

```
<div class="custom-file-upload">
            <!--<label for="file">File: </label>-->
            {{ form_widget(form.file, { 'attr': {'class':'file '} }) }} <br/><br/>
        </div>
```

any idea please about how I can validate the file.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the mimetype of the uploaded file by adding a constraint in the attribute file in your entity.

```
YourEntity
.... 
/**
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize = "2M",
     *     mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/x-pdf"},
     *     mimeTypesMessage = "You should upload a pdf file"
     * )
     */

private $faxtype;
```

Comment: I want to validate it in client side (javascript)